# Select sibling values of HTML

Tags: jquery, html, listview, siblings

Having troubling select the sibling values of my ListView with jQuery. Here is the jQuery syntax I'm trying but when I debug in firebug writing to console it says everything is undefined but when i view the html I can see values in them so I know there their it justs not selecting them. It is being called on the click event of Update button I need to grab the siblings of the distinct row in my listview for the row I'm updating.

```
        $('.nbr')
.click(function){
            var newaddr = $(this).siblings('#addr').val();
            var originaladdr = $(this).siblings('#addr').attr('data-Value');
            var newplace = $(this).siblings('#place').val();
            var originalplace = $(this).siblings('#place').attr('data-Value');
```

ListView:

```
    <asp:ListView runat="server" id="ListView1" >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table id="tablesorter" style="border:solid 1px black;width:55%;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <a href="#">Addr</a>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <a href="#">Place</a>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <input maxlength="3" size="4" type="text" id="addr" data-Value="" value="<%# Eval("addr")%>" />  
                   <input maxlength="4" size="4" type="text" id="place"  data-Value="" value="<%# Eval("place")%>" />  
                </td>
                <td>
                   <input type="button" class="nbr" id="btn_update" value="Update" />                     
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: What is `this` in this context? Where is this code called?

Comment: Your html structure is very strange. And what is `this`?

Comment: can you please post the generated HTML?

Comment: What this html generates is a listivew of addr and places for a person and so their will be multiple per person. When I clcik update next to each entry I want grab the values of addr and place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things that are siblings to `#addr` and `#place` are `#addr` and `#place`. They have no other siblings. So something is wrong this your logic. What are you trying to select from?

Also, since you appear to being using a template that will presumably be copied multiple times, you are going to have multiple elements with the same `id`. Use classes instead.

Finally, another tip, cache your jQuery objects instead of recreating the same ones.

**Edit:** Based on your update, your problem is that your button `nbr` is a cousin not a sibling to `#addr` and `#place`. What you will need to do is navigate from `nbr` to it's parent `td`, then from there to it's sibling `td` and then down to it's children.

Something like:

```
$(this).parent().prev().children("#addr");
```

Or more complete (after replacing your `id` with `class` instead):

```
$('.nbr').click(function){
    var parent = $(this).parent().prev();
    var addrNode = parent.children(".addr").first();
    var placeNode = parent.children(".place").first();

    var newaddr = addrNode.val();
    var originaladdr = addrNode.data('Value');
    var newplace = placeNode.val();
    var originalplace = placeNode.data('Value');
    // whatever you want to do with these values...
}
```

[Here's a fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/TCZph/)

Comment: addr and place are populated values so they do have distinct values

Comment: @ERead: I'm not talking about their values, I'm talking about their `id`s. You shouldn't have multiple HTML elements with the same `id`.

Comment: still says the values are undefined. I did this. var AddrNode = $(this).parent().prev().children("#addr");    var newaddr = AddrNode.val(); and it didnt work

Comment: I didn't assign eahc a class because all the element have the same class already defined in order to load values into data-Value attribute

Comment: @ERead: My mistake, I forgot to select the `first` element. `.children` returns a collection. On the class issue, yes you can. Your HTML is invalid if you have multiple elements with the same id. You can add multiple classes to the same element. So you could do `<input class="youOtherClass addr">` and still select it with `.addr`. Alternatively, you could select the children by their order (since it's defined in a template), so `var addrNode = parent.children()[0]` and `var placeNode = var addrNode = parent.children()[1]`, but this is a little more fragile.

Comment: This work but for some reason the originaladdr is the same as newaddr but it should be picking up the original value as opposed to after I change it.

Comment: @ERead: Try using `.data()` instead or `.attr()`. I've edited my answer.

Comment: NO that didn't work it went back to it being 'undefined'. data-Value attribute should hold the original value of the input and then I change it but I want to grab both changed value and original value but the original value also writes out to console as changed value

Comment: @Without seeing how you are setting the `data-Value` we're just shooting in the dark here. Maybe ask a separate question about that issue.